# Nunit и вызов exception

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, nunit

Делаю тесты для своей программы. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При определенных параметрах должна вызываться ошибка (кастомный exception). Как сделать проверку на это в юнит тестах? Делаю подобное

```
Assert.That(MyMethod(variable), Throws.TypeOf<MyException>());
```

Вызывается этот метод, выходит эта ошибка, но тест все равно не пройден. Видимо я что-то не так понимаю. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: `Assert.Throws<MyException>(() => MyMethod(variable));`?

Comment: [Assert.Throws](https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5) пробовали?

Comment: Тысяча благодарностей, получилось)

Comment: @Art отлично, оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для такого типа проверок используйте метод [`Assert.Throws`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Throws) или [`Assert.ThrowsAsync`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.ThrowsAsync) для тестирования асинхронных методов.

```
Assert.Throws<MyException>(() => MyMethod(variable));
```

NUnit 3 версии и выше имеет очень богатую документацию [на Github](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki), начните с неё.